# Sublime Text - Error trying to parse build system expected value

Tags: php, build, sublimetext2

Trying to create a PHP build to use within Sublime Text but receiving this error

"Error trying to parse build system: Expected value in C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\php.sublime-build:2:1

Code below

```
{"cmd”: [“php”, “$file”], 
“file_regex”: “php$”,
“selector”: “source.php”
}
```

New error message after editing the speech marks to standard form. This is displayed within the console after running the updated build.

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'php', u'C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\PHP\\exercise1.php']]
[dir:  C:\Users\James\Documents\PHP]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS     Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Ruby21\bin;C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm]
```

[Finished]

Comment: Different error message

Comment: Try to replace your typographic double quotes with normal ones: `"`

Comment: The build seems to run now thanks, but I'm now getting a different error message about the path location (inside the console within Sublime Text)

Comment: It doesn't look like `php.exe` is in your `PATH`. If you open a command prompt and type `php -v`, do you get any output?

Comment: I have PHP installed, but still can't get anywhere with this

Comment: That command didn't work in my cmd line, but I'm running PHP version 5.6.17 I went through the process yesterday and can see it from my localhost in my browser